# Getting MIME type of file (-Symfony 1.4)

Tags: php, mime-types, symfony-1.4, mime

Got a tricky problem, I must save files in DB.
Before doing so, we must verify the mime extension (don't trust user) of file uploaded, and if it's in our yml list.

Here's part of the code :

```
$verif_type_mime = sfYaml::load(sfConfig::get('sf_data_dir') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'verif_type_mime.yml');

$mime = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$mime_fichier = mime_content_type($filename);

$monfichier = fopen("debug.txt", 'a+');
fwrite($monfichier, print_r($mime_fichier, TRUE));
fclose($monfichier);
```

// RETURN NOTHING

```
if (in_array($mime_fichier, $verif_type_mime['verification'])) {
  // HERE I THOUGHT TO VERIFY IF IT WAS IN THE ARRAY OF $verif_mime_type
}
```

Send help please ^^'

Comment: Well have you tried to dump values of `$verif_type_mime` and `$mime_fichier`?

Comment: Done, it was a problem with bytea read as a string ._.